# IIS showing 404 error for CakePHP routing prefixes for instance located in subfolder

Tags: php, url-rewriting, 404, iis, subdirectory

I have this Single Page Application built using **AngularJS** that resides in the document root.

The SPA communicates with an API built using **CakePHP 3.5.x**. The CakePHP instance resides in a folder named `/api`. All requests from the SPA are sent to `www.example.com/api/some-action.json`. This is working out fine and no issues here.

However, I also have a administration backend built in the CakePHP and accessible via a CakePHP routing prefix of "admin".

If the Cake app were to reside in top-level documentroot, I could have easily accessed this via `www.example.com/admin`. Since the Cake app is in the api subfolder, I'm attempting to access it via `www.example.com/api/admin` and getting a 404 from IIS (default 404 page of IIS). 
[image]

If I simply access `www.example.com/api` - I drop to the default CakePHP start page that you see after a fresh installation... so no issues with the installation itself. 
[image]

And this URL structure works just fine on my local xampp instance with Apache.

Here are my IIS Rewrite rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Exclude direct access to webroot/*" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^webroot/(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite routed access to assets(img, css, files, js, favicon)" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(img|css|cache_css|font|files|js|audio|cache_js|favicon.ico|favicon-*.png|Favicon*.png|AndroidIcon*.png|manifest.json)(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="webroot/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>             
                <rule name="Rewrite requested file/folder to index.php" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Stack:

- Windows Server 2016
- IIS 10
- PHP 7.1
- AngularJS 1.6
- CakePHP 3.5.x
- Percona XtraDB (MySQL)

What tweaks in the rewrite rules do I need to carry out to get the CakePHP routing prefix(es) and any URL parts that follow to render properly? The rule should take care of `www.example.com/api/admin/*`.